# Set DropDownList value by selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and c#.  I'm trying to set the text in the dropdownlist box to display the current page title, but I cannot get it to work.  Can someone advise as to how to do it based on the code below?  Thanks!

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Websites\TaxMapCS";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileSystemInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");
        var result = string.Join(",", fi.OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());

        DropDownList1.DataSource = result.Replace(".aspx", "").Split(',');

        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Edition", ""));

    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + ".aspx");
}
```

Comment: just a side note. I would use string.Empty in place of using "". If you use "" and someone else comes along in the code they don't know if it was intentional or if someone forgot to place a value. string.Empty says I meant to pass an empty string.

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: Thanks Cubicle.Jockey, that's a good point.

Comment: D Stanley - it always defaults back to the first item in the list.  Everything else there works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + ".aspx");
}
```

Or

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ".aspx");
}
```

Comment: ***Who upvoted it?*** There is no such thing as `SelectedText` in ASP.Net DropDownList.

Comment: you're right about that. My mistake.
I've edited the post to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about ASP.NET, but in regular C#, I think you can try something like this:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(this.Page.Title);
```

Thanks to Cubicle.Jockey for helping me with the code.

Comment: I think it's this.Page.Title in regards to title. But I haven't done ASP.NET aspx style in awhile. MVC is were it's at. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split and join strings. Instead you can add individual ListItem to DropDownList.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string path = @"C:\DevelopmentArchive\TelerikDemo\TelerikDemo";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");

        foreach (var file in files.OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime))
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(file.Name.Replace(".aspx", ""), file.Name));

        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Edition", ""));
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't address my problem.

Comment: @eric You need to assign **both Text and Value** to `ListItem` in order to retrieve `SelectedItem.Value`. Look at **foreach loop** in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Websites\TaxMapCS";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileSystemInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.aspx");
        var result = string.Join(",", fi.OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());

        DropDownList1.DataSource = result.Replace(".aspx", "").Split(',');

        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Edition", ""));
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(Page.Title, ""));

    }
}


    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0)//do not redirect if 'Selected Edition' is selected
        {
            Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + ".aspx");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, it seems like my question isn't clear. Everything else works _except_ the current page being shown as selected in the dropdown.  SelectedValue does work.  Your suggestion does not set the dropdown to display the current item.  Thanks though.